# I am trying to pass Multiple Models to a single view using ViewModel .Unable to retrieve the check box selected values back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass Multiple Models to a single view using ViewModel with Employee,Skills,Skill Experience etc . I am trying to display check boxes for skills known by each employee, but unable to retrieve the selected values back to controller.

Here is my code:

Here is the ViewModelDemoController class:

```
public class ViewModelDemoController : Controller
{
    private EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
    public ActionResult ViewModelDemo()
    {
        ViewModelDemoVM vm = new ViewModelDemoVM();
        vm.allEmployees = db.Employees.ToList();
        vm.allSkills = db.Skills.ToList();
        ....
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

here is the view:

```
@model Project2.Models.ViewModelDemoVM
....
<table border="1" style="width:100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>DateOfBirth</th>
        <th>Address</th>
         ....
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.allEmployees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</td>
            ....
            <td>
                @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Checkbox", new { id = item.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (Model.allSkills.Count()); i++)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.allSkills[i].IsSelected)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.allSkills[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.allSkills[i].SkillName)
                        @Model.allSkills[i].SkillName
                    }
                    <input type="submit" value="AddSkills" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is the method in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, ViewModelDemoVM model,IEnumerable<int> selectedSkills, IEnumerable<SkillsViewModel> SSkills, SkillsExperience skill1)
{
    foreach (int SS in selectedSkills)
    {
        EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();
        skill1.EmpId = id;
        //skill1.SkillId= Convert.ToInt32(SS.Value);
        SkillsController sc = new SkillsController();
        //int sid = Convert.ToInt32(SS);
        skill1.SkillId = SS;
        skill1.YearsOfExperience = 4;
        db.SkillsExperiences.Add(skill1);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SkillsExperience");
}
```

Please help me how to retrieve selected values and update the values in db?

Comment: The model in your view is `ViewModelDemoVM` so your post method signature needs to be just `public ActionResult Index(int Id, ViewModelDemoVM model)`. But having multiple forms in a loop makes no sense (you can only submit one form)

Comment: But how to retrieve the selected values using the ViewModelDemoVM model. can you please help me?

Comment: `var selectedSkills = model.allSkills.Where(x => x.IsSelected);`

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Take note of my previous comment - your view makes no sense and is a confusing UI and has multiple failure points. Have either form with the checkbox lists for all employees so everything is edited at once, or redirect to a page that edits the skills for just one employee.